# geting error: 'await can not be used as an identifier within an async method or lambda expression'

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview, pagination

I am trying to implement pagination in datagridview using PagedList.

```
int pagenumber = 1;
```

`IPagedList<GetBillMani_Result> list;`

```
  public async Task<IPagedList<GetBillMani_Result>> GetPagedListAsync(int pagenumber = 1, int pageSize = 10)
    {
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        {
            using (ManiJayBharatEntities entity = new ManiJayBharatEntities())
            {
                var a = 15;
                return entity.GetBillMani(a, a).OrderBy(m => m.Name).ToPagedList(pagenumber, pageSize);
            }
        });
    }

private async void AllBill_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        list = await.GetPagedListAsync();  // <- getting error here
        btnPrev.Enabled = list.HasPreviousPage;
        btnNext.Enabled = list.HasNextPage;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = list.ToList();
        label3.Text = string.Format("Page {0}/{1}", pagenumber, list.PageCount);
    }
```

i am newbie to .net and c# any help would be appreciated. i am trying to implement pagination in winforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're getting the compiler error because there's a `.` in this bit of code: `await.GetPagedListAsync()`.

On a side note, your [usage of `Task.Factory.StartNew` is incorrect](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) (as I explain in full on my blog). Use `Task.Run` instead.